# Specflow 4 - Capture groups not binding in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: .net-core, bdd, specflow, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

Does anyone else have issues with adding step definitions in Specflow 4 with capture groups?
I've updated a project from **Specflow 2** to use **Specflow 4** and all my step definitions, including those with capture groups being binded correctly and the project can be run as expected.  However if I create a new project, any steps with capture groups are being bound.

### Current Platform setup:

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022
Version 17.1.0
VisualStudio.17.Release/17.1.0+32210.238
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.04084

Installed Version: Community

Node.js Tools   1.5.40105.1 Commit
NuGet Package Manager   6.1.0
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about
Visual Studio Extension for SpecFlow   1.0

SpecFlow.NUnit : 3.9
NUnit3TestAdapter: 4.1.0
FluentAssertions: 6.2
CucumberExpressions: 1.0.6
Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver: 99

### This is my BDD script

```
Scenario Outline: A valid user login to a travel website
   Given The home page is displayed
   **When I login as a valid <userType> user**
    Then the dashboard will be displayed
        
        Examples: 
        | userType |
        | agent    |
        | customer |
        | supplier |
```

I manually add the step definition into my binding class as follows, as I've always done previously

```
namespace Holiday
{
    [Binding]
    public class LoginPageStepDefinitions
    {
        [Given("The home page is displayed")]
        public void GivenTheHomePageIsDisplayed()
        {
            throw new PendingStepException();
        }
        [When(@"I login as a valid (agent|customer|supplier) user")]
        public void WhenILoginAsAValidAgentUser(string userType)
        {
            throw new PendingStepException();
        }

        [Then("the dashboard will be displayed")]
        public void ThenTheDashboardWillBeDisplayed()
        {
            throw new PendingStepException();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when I go back into the BDD, I see that the line isn't bound.  When I right click to give me a suggested step definition, I get the following suggestion:

```
 [When("I login as a valid agent user")]
 public void WhenILoginAsAValidAgentUser()
 {
    throw new PendingStepException();
 }
```

I've also created a StepArgumentTransformation but still being unbound.

Does anyone know if this a bug in the latest release of Specflow, or have they removed this feature?  I've reviewed their youtube video released Nov '21 and their is no mention of capture groups?

Many thanks.

Comment: What does the scenario title line look like? Please note that it should begin with `Scenario Outline: Some title` rather than `Scenario: Some title`.

Comment: Backticks and code on sperate lines now, so you should see correct BDD.

Comment: Does your step definition class have the `[Binding]` attribute above the class name?

Comment: Oh! You know what, there might be nothing wrong at all. Try closing all Visual Studio windows. Then delete the `.vs` folder in the root of your solution. Reopen Visual Studio and wait for bindings to be analyzed.

Comment: My step definition class is bound and I've removed the vs folder and done a rebuild.  Nothing. :(

Comment: Another possibly silly question, what if you outdent `Examples:` keyword so it is all the way left justified, or indented only one tab stop?

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio do you have? Which version of the SpecFlow extension for Visual Studio do you have?

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022
Version 17.1.0
VisualStudio.17.Release/17.1.0+32210.238
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.04084

Installed Version: Community

Specflow NUnit 3.9

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include that information. It is too easy to miss that in a comment.

Comment: Is there a gherkin syntax error before the scenario outline?